# ajax is not passing data

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms

I dont know why this is not working. Im trying to pass data through ajax. Iv used this many times but for some reason its not working. Its returning nothing.

here is the js

```
$('#contactformbtn').click(function(){
    var fullname = $('#fullname').val();
    var youremail = $('#youremail').val();
    var subject = $('#subject').val();
    var yourmessage = $('#yourmessage').val();

    var datastring = 'fullname=' + fullname + '&youremail=' + youremail + '&subject=' + subject + '&yourmessage=' + yourmessage;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax-contact.php",
        data: datastring,
        success: function(status){
            alert(status);
        }
    });

    //alert(datastring);
    return false;
});
```

and this is the php

```
<?php
require 'core/init.php';

if(isset($_POST)){
    $fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
    $youremail = $_POST['youremail'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    echo $fullname;
}
?>
```

in chrome im checking the console and im getting 2 errors

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '3' of null
```

My full js is this, (just incase the error is not the contact function)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#download-btn").bind("click", downloadfile);
$(".download-link").hide();

function downloadfile()
{
    var dl = $("#dl").val();
    var counter = 10;

    var interval = setInterval(function(e) {
        counter--;

        if(counter > 0){
            $("#download-btn").html("Your Download will begin in " + counter + " Seconds");
            $("#download-btn").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        } else {
            window.location.href="http://www.forwardfiles.com/get_file.php?i="+dl;
            $("#download-btn").hide();
            $(".download-status").html("<h3 class='center'>Download is complete</h3>");
            clearInterval(interval);
        }

    }, 1000);
}


$('#contactformbtn').click(function(){
    var fullname = $('#fullname').val();
    var youremail = $('#youremail').val();
    var subject = $('#subject').val();
    var yourmessage = $('#yourmessage').val();

    var datastring = 'fullname=' + fullname + '&youremail=' + youremail + '&subject=' + subject + '&yourmessage=' + yourmessage;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax-contact.php",
        data: datastring,
        success: function(status){
            alert(status);
        }
    });

    //alert(datastring);
    return false;
});

});
```

Comment: what line/file is giving the error?

Comment: i dont know, everything is working, but the contact function is not sending the data to the php file

Comment: the console should give you the actual line that's throwing the error

Comment: There's a few things you can try. `console.log(datastring)` to make sure your string looks correct. If it does, `var_dump($_REQUEST)` in your PHP file to see what/how it's being passed.

Comment: ok, its passing the data in console.log but the strange thing is that in the php its passing an empty array

Comment: wait, iv worked something out, its not passing anything to the php file

Comment: have considered using the format `data: { "fullname": fullname , ...}`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [.serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)?

```
$('#contactformbtn').click(function(){
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax-contact.php",
    data: $("form").serialize(),
    success: function(status){
        alert(status);
    }
});

//alert(datastring);
return false;
```

});

Comment: tryed, its still not passing anything

Comment: its strange, i tryed this code outside my website and it worked, so there must be something wrong with something in my site

Answer (score 0):

Check in your HTML code if these values

```
var fullname = $('#fullname').val();
    var youremail = $('#youremail').val();
    var subject = $('#subject').val();
    var yourmessage = $('#yourmessage').val();
```

Have defined their id's and not only "name" tags

Comment: yeah iv looked, they are there

Comment: Check in your ajax-contact.php the name of the message variable is "message" and in your ajax code it's "yourmessage" there is your error, i tried your code and that was the error the server brought up, try it and tell me if it worked for you

Answer (score 0):

I got it working, the code i had was fine. the problem was i wasnt running php version 5.3, so i updated it and its working :D. Thanks for you help anyway